# Mutable Value in Firebase Push Notification Node.js 10 correct syntax?

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mutable

I am trying to add Mutable_Content to my push notifications so I can add a badge count.
However I am running into the error:

```
Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.mutable_content" property. Values must be strings.
```

[image]

Here is my code for the payload:

[image]

```
const payload = { 
   notification : { 
      title: owner + ' has made a post',
         body: title + ' - ' + caption,
            mutable_content : true
    },
};
```

I have tried many different tutorials to figure out the right syntax but it is not working.
It always comes up with an error.

I am using node.js 10 for the engine and firebase/google cloud platform to trigger the function.

Can anyone help me with this syntax?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found unrelated and outdated firebase documentation about it. But you can bypass this by adding a `apns` field where you can directly put data for the apple notification service. But beware to use the apple syntax with hyphen.

See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

```
  var message = {
    notification: {
      title: "my notification title",
      body: "hello"
    },    
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          'mutable-content': true
        }
      }
    },
```